# C# - Entity Framework Core : build a dynamic expression from multiple expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, expression

I have an entity called `Product` and inside it a navigation property called `ProductAttributes`.

I need to get products with multiple conditions like this:

```cs
var products = context.Products
    .Include(x => x.ProductAttributes)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Attribute)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.ProductAttributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeId == attributesIds[0]) != null 
                && x.ProductAttributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeId == attributesIds[1]) != null
                && x.ProductAttributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeId == attributesIds[2]) != null);
```

I've tried to build the expression dynamically, but all of my tries failed.

This is the code I've written:

```cs
var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "x");

var left = Expression.Property(arg, "ProductAttributes");
var right = Expression.Constant(null);

var exp = Expression.NotEqual(left, right);

Expression<Func<Product, bool>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, bool>>(exp, arg);

foreach (var id in attributesIds)
{
     var searchArg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ProductAttribute), "z");
     var searchLeft = Expression.Property(searchArg, "AttributeId");
     var searchRight = Expression.Constant(id);
     var searchExp = Expression.Equal(searchLeft, searchRight);

     Expression<Func<ProductAttribute, bool>> searchExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<ProductAttribute, bool>>(searchExp, searchArg);
     Expression<Func<Product, bool>> subExpression = x => x.ProductAttributes.AsQueryable().Where(searchExpression).FirstOrDefault() != null;

     var andExp = Expression.And(expression.Body, subExpression.Body);
     expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, bool>>(andExp, arg);
}

var products = context.Products.Include(x => x.ProductAttributes)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Attribute)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(expression);
    // .Where(x => x.ProductAttributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeId == attributesIds[0]) != null);

return Ok(products);
```

The error I get is:

> The LINQ expression 'x' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

So, how can I create this expression? Or what is the wrong in my code?

Comment: First, you don't need those `Include`s unless you need to force eager loading. Second, you can write `Where(x=>attributeIds.Contain(x.AttributeId)` to generate a `x.AttributeID in (1,4,7,123,...)` clause in SQL. You don't need to dynamically generate anything. `FirstOrDefault` is mainly a `TOP 1` clauses, not a filtering clause.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? What is `ProductAttributes` ? This smells strongly of the Entity-Attribute_Value **anti**pattern (ie very bad idea). Instead of making your code easier to modify, you just made it a *lot* harder to write and query. You can't fix a bad design with queries. If anything, you have to "pivot" the EAV schema back into a proper table just to query it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos for the idea of using `Contain(x.AttributeId)` I need to get the products which have productAttributes have attributeId=1 **AND** attributeId=2 ...etc, and using `Where(x=>attributeIds.Contain(x.AttributeId)` I got products have productAttributes have attributeId=1 **OR** attributeId=2 ...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ProductAttributes is an entity which create a relation between Products table and Attributes table as well.

Comment: Why a separate `Attributes` table instead of columns? That's the problem here, not LINQ. You're trying to find a single product that has 3 specific attribute values but you can't perform a simple `WHERE field1=@val1 AND field2=@val2 AND field3=@val3`. LINQ can't do anything that can't be done in SQL and the SQL query you'd want for this would be very complex. You don't need such a schema in the first place. SQL Server allows over 30000 sparse columns. You can use XML or JSON fields to store "bags" of extra attributes too

Comment: If you want fast queries though, some fields *have* to be proper columns that can be indexed. They can even be indexed computed columns that pull specific data from an XML or JSON field - the server will persist them as normal columns but update them every time the source changes. You can't do that with an EAV schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an answer yet, but I think you have to build the following filter,  which much more simpler

```cs
.Where(x => x.ProductAttributes
    .Count(a => attributesIds.Contains(a.AttributeId)) == attributesIds.Length
);
```

Comment: Greeeeeat!! this worked for some cases, I'll check the rest of the cases and mark this as a solution, thanks man.